# Git cherrypick error

Tags: git

Sincerely, I don't know how to phrase everything perfectly, but let's try.

I'm trying to git cherry-pick into remote branch of mine (let say sv/abc)
for example:

```
    git cherry-pick b965749428dd3ec934614364d73158ac0bc121f8
```

At first, i'm having an error message of:

```
    error: could not apply b965749... Changes 123
    hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
    hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
    hint: and commit the result with 'git commit -c b965749'
    myAccount$ git status
    # On branch sv/abc
    # Unmerged paths:
    #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
    #   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
    #
    #       both modified:      fileA
    #       both modified:      fileB
    #
    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So, i went ahead and change the resolve the conflicts in both files by:

Vim the file
Remove `<<<<<<HEAD`
Remove everything between `>>>>> xxx` and `========` inclusively

then `git add <file>`
Here's the weird part, when I issue git status again, it doesn't appear that it's ready to be committed, I mean nothing is staged

then `git commit -c b965749` stated that nothing to be committed

Then `git push` Stated that it's already up-to-date

Then what i did is try everything all over again but this time, issuing `git reset <file>`

Well, it does the magic this time, but new issue i'm facing is that this hash tag is previously committed by different Author.
When I issued `git push`, I have an error message of 'invalid author'

How do i go from here?

Comment: What did you `git add`?

Comment: the edited file
git add fileA
git add fileB

Comment: So you want to reset the author information? `git commit --amend --reset-author`

Comment: Preferably not to, the reason using git commit -c is to preserve the author information, so that we can keep track of the author changes and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You resolved the conflict by removing all changes. Thus, `git status` determines that this file should be unchanged in the resulting commit, so it becomes unstaged. When you do this to all files, the commit becomes empty, so there is no point in recording it.

You are asking to cherry-pick the commit, but do not integrate any of its changes, so why do you cherry-pick in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

when you are doing the remove part, your are removing changes so the file is as it was when you started the merge so there is no changes.

I you really want a merge commit in your repository you can do git commit --allow-empty as your commit is not making any changes.